# number of element in a principal ideal domain can be $25/36/35/15$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains

Could any one tell me number of element in a principal ideal domain can be $25/36/35/15$ ?

I just know a principal ideal domain is generated by a single element. what the knowledge I need to find this result?

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, you need to know that any finite integral domain is a field. Then you should know that there is a finite field of cardinality $n$ if and only if $n$ is a prime power.

Note that what you said is probably not what you meant:

> a principal ideal domain is generated by a single element.

In any ring $R$, we have that $R$ is equal to the ideal generated by $1_R$, so this is true,  but the statement you probably meant is

> **every ideal of** a principal ideal domain is generated by a single element.

Comment: " any finite integral domain is a field"... +1 for this hint :) So, principal ideal domain is field in this case and as cardinality has to be a prime power, the possible cardinality should be $25=5^2$ ...  Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

25 elements can have a principal ideal  domain because for if n is p^2 then there exist a field of order P^2 moreover since a field is pid then every ideal is principal.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).